# How do I make a equation using filter where I am doing 20< and up?

Tags: r

players_ppg <- filter(players_stats,career_PTS== max(career_PTS))%>%
select(name,college,career_PTS) #selects the columns that you want showed
View(players_ppg)

The code works fine but it isnt what I am trying to get. I want to do a equation where I am getting players that had 25 or up in there total career but I have tried putting in equations and it hasnt worked. Do i remove the max function and try it in a different way? The max function only gets me 1 player but I want to do multiple since its over 25 instead of having a max. I assume its like 0<25<= but idk I need help

Comment: Do you mean `players_ppg <- filter(players_stats,career_PTS >25)` ? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: thank you it works